# Passing JSESSIONID with httprequest

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using a worklight http adapter, I am trying to send a http request with a JSESSIONID to a backend server.  Currently this is how I am formatting the request:

```
var input = {
        method : 'post',
        path : '(path)',
        parameters : {
            (parameters)
        },
        headers : {(headers)},
        cookies : {'JSESSIONID' : secureCookie}
};

var alertResponse = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

However, after reviewing the response on the server side the request doesn't seem to be passing the JSESSIONID right.  I realize this is a hard problem to solve given the information, but I wanted to make sure that this is the correct way to send this cookie and that there isn't some known issue with JSESSIONID's already.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<procedure>` element of the adapter XML file You need to set the `connectAs` Attribute with the value `endUser` and then the connection to the back end is created with the user's identity.

Comment: Doesn't this only apply if you are using authentication between the WL server and the client?  Currently I am just having the client invoke a procedure on the adapter that does a http request to a login page, and the login page returns the JSESSIONID that I am eventually passing.